# Instagram automate comments

Tags: javascript, dom, instagram

I am trying to do some automation for Instagram comments. Here is my code:

```
var comment_text = document.getElementsByClassName('Ypffh')[0];
comment_text.click();
comment_text.focus();

var text = "This is my comment :)";
var l = text.length;
var current = 0;
var time = 100;

var write_text = function() {
  comment_text.value += text[current];
  if (current < l - 1) {
    current++;
    setTimeout(function() {
      write_text()
    }, time);
  } else {
    comment_text.setAttribute('value', comment_text.value);
    comment_text.textContent = comment_text.value;
  }
}
setTimeout(function() {
  write_text()
}, time);

setTimeout(function() {
  var submit_button = document.getElementsByClassName('y3zKF')[0];
  submit_button.disabled = false;
  submit_button.click();

  var comment_form = document.getElementsByClassName('X7cDz')[0];
  comment_form.submit();
}, 2000);
```

But after running this code I can see the following:

1. Comment text is typing in the textarea, as expected. But! The "Post" (comment) button stay disabled. If I type a text by myself - this button  got enable.
2. As can be seen in the code - after finish typing, this button is forcibly activated and receives a "click" event, but nothing happens.
3. Then the form receives a "submit" event - but I have just an error page from Instagram, that's all.

So the question: what I am doing wrong? I know about a headless solutions, like Puppeteer, or about using a direct request to https://www.instagram.com/web/comments/[POST_ID]/add/ with a correct CSRF token, but I heed to do it via DOM manipulation. Is this possible? Will be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setter `value` is not working as you wanted because React library overrides input value setter, but you can call the function directly on the input as context.

```
var nativeInputValueSetter = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window.HTMLTextAreaElement.prototype, "value").set;
nativeInputValueSetter.call(comment_text, "This is my comment :)");

var ev2 = new Event('input', { bubbles: true});
comment_text.dispatchEvent(ev2);
```

This should properly update the value and enable the `post` button for submitting the comment

Comment: Thank you! It's exactly what I need and this works to me!